# Jetpack Compose Interoperability: Button elevation missing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently migrating to Jetpack Compose. When I try to create a custom button by using `AndroidView()` for interoperability, the elevation/shadow is gone.
How can the elevation be maintained?

Example:

```
AndroidView(factory = {
    MaterialButton(it).apply {
        text = "Hello"
    }
}, modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
```

With the MaterialButton used in the example it doesn't work either, but the purpose is to integrate a custom button.

Comment: Not sure why that is but try putting your Android View inside a Surface and apply an elevation to the Surface. See if it works.

Comment: Did you determine how to add elevation to a button and/or arbitrary composables?

Comment: I didn't check it further on AndroidView but for composables in general you can use the `Modifier.shadow(...)` attribute.